# How to check if dropdown is disabled?

Tags: jquery

Using jquery how do i simply check if it is read only?

this is what i am trying..

```
$("#item").keydown(function (event) {
     //alert(event.keyCode);
     if (event.keyCode == 13) {
         $("#ok").click();               
         if ($('#dropLength').prop("disabled") == false) {
             $("#dropLength").focus();
             return;
         }
         if ($('#dropUnit').prop("disabled") == false) {
             $("#dropUnit").focus();
             return;
         }
         $("#qty").focus();                
         return ;
     }
 });
```

The dropdowns are set to readonly using jquery also:

```
if ($('#dropLength').find('option').length <= 1) {
      $('#dropLength').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
if ($('#dropUnit').find('option').length <= 1) {
      $('#dropUnit').attr("disabled", "disabled");
}
```

Comment: By readonly you mean disabled?

Comment: Please note that HTML defines two attributes that are related but different: `readonly` and `disabled`.

Answer (score 126, accepted):

The legacy solution, before 1.6, was to use `.attr` and handle the returned value as a `bool`. The main problem is that the returned type of `.attr` has changed to `string`, and therefore the comparison with `== true` is broken (see http://jsfiddle.net/2vene/1/ (and switch the jquery-version)).

With 1.6 `.prop` was introduced, which returns a `bool`.

Nevertheless, I suggest to use [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/), as the returned type is intrinsically `bool`, like:

```
$('#dropUnit').is(':disabled');
$('#dropUnit').is(':enabled');
```

Furthermore `.is()` is much more natural (in terms of "natural language") and adds more conditions than a simple attribute-comparison (eg: `.is(':last')`, `.is(':visible')`, ... please see [documentation on selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)).

Comment: This answer has incorrect and misleading information. It is completely fine to use `$('#dropLength').prop("disabled") == false` with JQuery 1.6+. It works just fine. @Andreas is confusing `$('#dropLength').attr("disabled")` (which will not return `false/true`) with `$('#dropLength').prop("disabled")` (which will return `false/true`). It is completely safe to use `$('#dropLength').prop("disabled")` as a boolean. http://jsfiddle.net/nsnomatz/

Comment: @DougS I am absolutely not confusing `.prop` with `.attr`, as my usage of `.attr` was on porpuse and explicit in the fiddle. As I've mentioned in my answer: the returned type of `.attr` has changed to `string` (as the value of the attribute is a string), and many legacy implementations depend on `.attr` (as `.prop` was introduced with 1.6) returning a `bool`. That is also the reason why I would never go for an explicit checking with `.attr` nor `.prop` and rather do a `.is` with an appropriate pseudo-class.

Comment: You're going to confuse the hell out of people who read your answer and think `prop` is broken. It's not broken! It works just fine. The original question doesn't even use the code you're referring to. He's using `prop` correctly. And now you've clarified in your comment that you prefer to use `is` just in case `prop` stops working in the future. Fix your answer so people know that `prop` is not broken and works just fine as a boolean.

Comment: @DougS I did never ever say anything about `.prop`, but I will add a clarification on this, as I see your point - thanks! And, I did always suggest `is`, for many reasons: May it be similarity to natural language, multiple scenarios where you don't want to query attributes (like `:last`...) and so on ... Btw, for further comments: Please watch your tongue, your comment is quite harsh!

Comment: The rebuke was justified. The OP's question never mentioned anything about using `attr` as a boolean, so this answer went off on a tangent that made it seem as if the OP's `prop` code was wrong. I know this answer caused me confusion and lost time, and given the number of upvotes there's a good chance several people got the impression that `prop` was broken. Thank you for editing the answer.

Comment: I prefer `prop` over `is`. They both have the same result, however, `prop` is faster. http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/7

Comment: @DougS The range of influence (due to upvotes) of my answer makes such an edit inevitable! Nevertheless: The performance boost (100%) you gain with `.prop` (for `:checked`) doesn't make me wanna go for it, due to the reasons I've mentioned. And, [doing a performance test with `:enabled`](http://jsperf.com/prop-vs-ischecked/68) shows no real world impact to me...

Answer (score 7):

Try following or check demo [disabled](http://jsfiddle.net/2vene/5/) and [readonly](http://jsfiddle.net/2vene/4/)

```
$('#dropUnit').is(':disabled') //Returns bool
$('#dropUnit').attr('readonly') == "readonly"  //If Condition
```

You can check [jQuery FAQ](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F) .

Answer (score 3):

There are two options:

**First**

You can also use like  [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is)

```
$('#dropDownId').is(':disabled');
```

**Second**

Using `== true` by checking  if the attributes value is `disabled`.  [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr)

```
$('#dropDownId').attr('disabled');
```

whatever you feel fits better , you can use :)

Cheers!

Comment: DO NOT USE `== true` or `== false` - the usage is broken by around 1.6! see my answer and the link to test!

Comment: @Manish Can this be used only for disabled? I used it to check enabled and it fails!!

Comment: Ignore Andreas comment above. It's partially incorrect. He's confusing `attr('disabled')` with `prop('disabled')`. Using `prop('disabled')` as a boolean works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for something like this, because I've got to check which of all my selects are disabled.

So I use this:

```
let select= $("#select");

for (let i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
    const element = select[i];
    if(element.disabled == true ){
        console.log(element)
    }
}
```