# How do I check if Dropdown List is readonly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo, xpages

I want to check if a dropdown list is readonly. I have this dropdown on my xpage inside repeat control and based on certain condition one of my dropdown will be in readonly. I want to check which one is in readonly using CSJS (javascript, jquery, dojo)

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/9062788/3518203

Comment: `$('select').prop('readonly')` returns true/false

Comment: I wouldn't render the dropdown at all, but instead render a computed field with the value. Makes a cleaner interface and you only need to check: is it there?

Comment: Yes it is exactly what is happening it is not rendering dropdown, instead a table is created and the table is having dropdown id. I wanted to set values to those dropdown but as the readonly dropdown is not rendering, I am not able to do so.

Comment: And if I make that dropdown disabled then its value wont be submitted to the server, so again in trouble. Inside repeat control I am having few dropdowns and I want to restrict user from changing values of dropdown which matches a certain condition, thats why I was trying to make it disable or readonly, but either is not serving the purpose.

Comment: You don't make it readonly, you don't render it. Instead render a computed text. This way you can check if the client id exists. If not -> not there, "readonly". By now I suspect, that you need to take a step back and look at the use case you want to achieve. So explain the business functionality in a question update (or a new one) - there might be a better solution than read-only dropdown checks

Answer (score 1):

you can using jquery with few ways:

**1st Way:**

```
if($('select').attr('disabled'))
{
    alert("read only");
}
```

[**Fiddle Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/K5hzr/)

**2nd way:**

```
  if($('select').is(':disabled'))
     {
       alert("read only");
     }
```

**3rd way:**

```
if($('select').attr('readonly'))
    {
        alert("read only");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your dropdown is an XPages control of type xp:combobox, you can do the following to check if the control is readonly using server-side logic:

```
getComponent("<id of combobox>").isReadonly()
```

As you mention yourself, a readonly combobox in XPages is not rendered as a dropdown but as a table with an id of your combobox.

Comment: Henrik, I am writing client side javascript and getComponent() would work in SSJS. I tried invoking getComponent() from CSJS 
`var valchk = '#{javascript:getComponent("cbApproverList").isReadonly()}'; alert(valchk);` 
It is throwing error..

Comment: isReadonly does not work well for me. Instead `com.ibm.xsp.util.FacesUtil.isComponentReadOnly(facesContext,getComponent(xxx))` does the job.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this with jQuery methods:

```
alert($('select[readonly]').attr('id')); 
// alerts the id of readonly select element
```

if there are multiple readonly select elements then you can store the ids in an array with `.map()` method:

```
var readOnly = $('select[readonly]').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

#### [Demo @ fiddle with readonly attribute.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke54u/)

or if you meant for `disabled` then you can change to this script:

```
alert($('select[disabled]').attr('id'));
```

or

```
var readOnly = $('select[disabled]').map(function(){
    return this.id;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As we know a readonly combobox in XPages is not rendered as a dropdown but as a table with an id of combobox.
If we try to set some values to the readonly dropdown it wont be visible as the readonly dropdown gets rendered as table and that table has value property.

So, I created a span element on runtime for showing my readonly combobox value with the id of my combobox and used visible property of dropdown instead of readonly property so that even table doesn't gets created.

```
function setValues()
{
 //START OF CODE: Set values on dialog      
 var RepID = "#{id:repeatControlID}"
 var totalcont = "#{javascript:getComponent('repeatControlID').getRowCount()}";

 var val = "#{javascript: DataSourceObj.getItemValue('docField')}"

 for(i=0;i<val.length;i++)
 {  
   var idChL = RepID+":"+i+":comboboxID"; 
   var cbCell = RepID+":"+i+":cbCell"; //cbCell is my id of table cell in which my combobox is present
   var element = document.getElementById(idChL);            
   if(element) //Check if dropdown is rendered, if not then create element on fly
   {
 element.value = val;
   }
   else{        
  createEle(idChL,cbCell,val);
   }                
 }      
 //END OF CODE: Set values on dialog
}   

function createEle(idText,cbCell,idVal)
{
    var input = document.createElement("span");
    input.innerText = idVal;
    input.id = idText;
    var parentEle = document.getElementById(cbCell);
    parentEle.appendChild(input);
}
```